# Sending the same objects with different fields over an object serialized stream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serialization

I have a client/server program, and I'm sending objects through `ObjectOutputStream` via `writeObject()` and `readObject()`.

The object I'm sending is class consisting of a couple of fields, and another object inside (let's call the outer object `Wrapper` and the inner `Inner`. Both the custom objects implement `serializable`.

The first time I send the `Wrapper` over, everything works flawlessly. Everything stored in both `Wrapper`, `Inner` and all the fields serialize and deserialize without problems.

However, when the client then modifies the `Inner` class, puts it in the `Wrapper`, and sends it one more time, the `Inner` instance received by the server, is identical to the one received the first time around.

My client:

```java
Inner inner = new Inner();
inner.setValue("value");

ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(new Wrapper(inner));
```

Server:

```java
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper) in.readObject();
String value = wrapper.getInner().getValue();
```

Client then modifies the `Inner` class (same instance as before) with a DIFFERENT string (ie. containing other letters then the first one):

```java
inner.setValue("newValue");
out.writeObject(new Wrapper(inner));
```

However, when I look at the `inner.getValue()` on the server, it has not changed and is still equal to `"value"`.

I solved this, by making a hard copy of the inner class, before sending it over:

```java
Inner newInner = new Inner();
newInner.setValue("newValue");
out.writeObject(new Wrapper(newInner));
```

The new value now is updated as it should.

Why does serialization work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).  To quote from the Javadocs:

> Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written.

Since you are using the same inner class reference, it just sends over a reference to the previously sent object.  It does *not* check all of the fields of all of the objects to see if any of them have changed.  I suspect that not only was `inner.getValue()` equal to the first object sent but that the `inner` object received by the server in the 2nd object was the *same object* (`==`) as the `inner` from the first object.

If you had called:

```
out.reset();
```

before the sending of the object with the adjusted `inner` field, your code should work.  The `reset()` method clears the reference cache which helps the serialization stream be efficient.  As a side note, `reset()` is especially necessary if you are sending a *large* number of temporary objects across a stream because otherwise these objects are cached in memory and can cause heap exhaustion.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. I'll mark it as the answer when I'm allowed to do so. Also, thanks for editing the title. I didn't really know what to put. Appreciated!